# draw line on tablerow programmatically

Tags: android, line, tablerow, stroke

I want to draw a horizontal line in middle of a tablerow like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />    
<stroke android:width="2dip" 
    android:color="#FF0000" android:dashWidth="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

but with java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't added the java code for your table row, I'll do assumptions:

Assume the code you have is in the xml file named **`line.xml`** inside Drawable folder,
Assume we have `TableRow myRow = new TableRow(this);`

Now we will convert **`line.xml`** to a Drawable in Java code,

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable line = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.line);
```

Now you just have to add it inside a view to put it in middle of your table row, for example:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setBackground(line);
```

Then add it inside your table row,

```
myRow.addView(tv);
```

I didn't try it but you can give it a shot, Good luck